# How do I assign a new, unique ID to a cloned HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

A project I'm working on requires of form of which its textareas need to be duplicated if the user him/herself requires that. The element is cloned and appended to **#mp** when the button, selector **#AddAnswer** is clicked. I've been trying to assign the ID's with the following JQuery code:

```
$('#AddAnswer').click(
    function() {
        for(var i=0; i<=10;i++)
            $clone=$('textarea[name="antwoord"]:first').clone().attr('id', 'list'+i);
            console.log($clone);
            $('#mp').append($clone);
            return false;
});
```

This unfortunately only assigns the number 10 behind the selector "#line". Can anyone help me to slightly tweak this code so that the ID's just increments by one as an element is cloned?

Comment: So you want to create ten clones when you click on AddAnswer and each them each an incremental id?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie - I need to duplicate the textareas so that administrative users can fill in the answering options for making multiple choice questions. In this case, I just tried to used 10 in the condition of the for statement to test the code. Of course, 10 wouldn't be the best amount of options to choose from. We also have very picky and wishy-washy people in this world. Again, as I clone the element, I'd like the number in the id to be incremented by 1.

Comment: if you can, I think it would be a good idea to camelCase your html elements.  addAnswer is more standard than AddAnswer

Comment: You're right. I should do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would generate a new index based on the amount of elements you already have

```
$('#AddAnswer').on("click",function() {
    var idx = $('textarea[name^="antwoord"]').length+1,
        $clone = $('textarea[name^="antwoord"]:first').clone().attr('id', 'antwoord_'+idx );
    $('#mp').append($clone);
    return false;
});
```

test on http://fiddle.jshell.net/Uj5W7/2/

another possibility would be to work with `index()`

```
$('#AddAnswer').on("click",function() {
    var idx = $('textarea[name^="antwoord"]:last').index()+1,
        $clone = $('textarea[name^="antwoord"]:first').clone().attr('id', 'antwoord_'+idx );
    $('#mp').append($clone);
    return false;
});
```

test on http://fiddle.jshell.net/Uj5W7/3/

Comment: Is there a way to append/prepend the letter for the answer based on the stated amount of answers in variable 'idx'? Is an if statement necessary?

Comment: dont know if i understand you correctly: You could wrap a `li` around `textarea` with `list-style-type: decimals`. see here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Uj5W7/4/. Or: just add the index before the textarea with `$clone.before(idx)`. in this case you should use the `.length+1` possibility

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code :

```
//Defaults to 1
var numAnswers = 1;

$('#AddAnswer').click(function() {
    //Gets the clone and sets the ID to be list + Number of Answers
    $clone = $('textarea[name="antwoord"]:first').clone().attr('id', 'list'+numAnswers);
    console.log($clone);
    $('#mp').append($clone);
    //Add 1 to number of answers
    numAnswers += 1;

    return false;
});
```

This will add a textarea to the control every time the AddAnswer button is clicked.

If you want to add more than one at a time try the following :

```
//Defaults to 1
var numAnswers = 1;

$('#AddAnswer').click(function() {
    var numToAdd = 10;
    var startNum = numAnswers + 1;
    var endNum = numToAdd + numAnswers;        

    for(var i=startNum; i <= endNum;i++) {
        //Gets the clone and sets the ID to be list + current Answer number
        $clone = $('textarea[name="antwoord"]:first').clone().attr('id', 'list'+i);
        console.log($clone);
        $('#mp').append($clone);
        //Add 1 to number of answers
        numAnswers += 1;            
    }
    return false;
});
```

The second approach adds 10 items at a time and will add to the number of items, i.e. first time it will add items up to 11, then items up to 21, etc.

Comment: This worked great! Though, I would like the amount of textareas to be indexed as described in the solution above.

Is there a way to append/prepend the letter for the answer based on the stated amount of answers in variable 'idx'? Is an if statement necessary?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by append/prepend the letter. What exactly is the "letter" you are referring to? jQuery can Append/Prepend using the following methods respectively : [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Comment: What I mean by "letter" is the letter that belongs with the answer option. Like answer "A." or answer "B.". I'd like the letter automatically assigned to the answer option as the textarea is cloned.

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything about assigning a letter to the textarea in your question. Please add this to your question to better describe what you are stuck on.

Comment: I will next time. For now, I have already found out how to assign those letters to the textareas. Gotta' do something without any help at times...

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
            $('#AddAnswer').click(function() {
                for(var i=0; i<=10;i++)
                {
                    $clone=$('textarea[name="antwoord"]:first').clone().attr('id', 'list'+i);
                    $('#mp').append($clone);
                }
                return false;
            });
```